# Google app engine swf file not showing

Tags: google-app-engine

I tried to use flash gallery at GAE, but it doesn't work.
the flashgallery.swf is not showing.
I'm using www.labnol.org/internet/host-website-on-google-app-engine/18801/ for gae hosting, and trying to use www.flash-gallery.org/features.html for flash gallery.
The flash galley contains

flashgallery.html - can see flash gallery here
flashgallery.php
flashgallery.swf
swfobject.js
default.xml - colour settings
img - folder for galley image

the script in flashgallery.html is

```
<!-- Script that embeds gallery. -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var so = new SWFObject("flashgallery.swf", "gallery", "770", "1300", "8"); // Location of SWF file. You can change gallery width and height here (using pixels or percents).
so.addParam("quality", "high");
so.addParam("allowFullScreen", "true");
so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
so.addVariable("content_path","img"); // Location of a folder with JPG and PNG files (relative to php script).
so.addVariable("color_path","default.xml"); // Location of XML file with settings.
so.addVariable("script_path","flashgallery.php"); // Location of PHP script.
//so.addVariable("api_key","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); // Flickr API key.
so.write("gallery");
</script>
```

and flashgallery.php here
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8rRNUE8dnLZY3doM3lmTXc3RjQ/edit?usp=sharing

I don't know what is the problem. is the php file problem? I heard GAE now support php...
I deployed flashgallery folder including these files, and went to ***.appspot.com/flashgallery/flashgallery.html but nothing came out. the flash was there, but just white screen. when i right-clicked it, it said 'Movie not loaded'

Answer (score 0):

1)open app.yaml in notepad or other text-editor application

2)and copy paste following codes

```
application: yourApplicationname
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|swf|php))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|swf|php))

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots.txt 

- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

3) save the file and upload it to appengine

*note yourApplicationname should the name of your actual application name.

This worked for me